# Update marker when filtering data using ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, leaflet

I'm facing problem when filtering the location marker isn't updating, old marker remains there new marker keeps on adding on old one.

I have used `map.removeLayer()` also but nothing seems to work If I use this function after success call it will always remove marker.

```
$('#filter').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:"{{ url('filter-opportunities-grid') }}",
            data: {
                'status':status,
            },
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(res){
            var addressPoints = res[8];
             if (markers != null) {
                  map.removeLayer(markers);
             }

                //Color according to types
                var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
                    for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
                        var a = addressPoints[i];
                        var title = a.title;
                        var due_date = a.due_date;
                        var type = a.type;
                        var address = a.url;

                       if(type==0) {
                                var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a.lat,a.lng), {  title: title, icon:red});
                        }
                        if(type==1) {
                                var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a.lat,a.lng), {  title: title, icon:orange});
                        }
                        if(type==2) {
                                var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a.lat,a.lng), {  title: title, icon:yellow});
                        }
                        if(type==3) {
                                var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a.lat,a.lng), {  title: title, icon:green});
                        }
                        if(type==4) {
                                var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a.lat,a.lng), {  title: title, icon:blue});
                        }
                        marker.bindPopup('<a class="text-info" href='+address+'><i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>'+title+'<br>Date de fin:'+due_date);
                        markers.addLayer(marker);
                        map.addLayer(markers);
                    }                     
            }  
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried defining markers outside of your function?

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
```

Is markers in a scope where the following ever gets called?

```
if (markers != null) {
  map.removeLayer(markers);
}
```